# kernal version error while installing php

Tags: kernel, php

The currently running kernel version is 5.15.0-50-generic which is not the expected kernel version 5.15.0-52-generic. Restarting the system to load the new kernel will not be handled automatically, so you should consider rebooting.

Comment: This looks like some out of context error message. What is the question? What command produced this? What version of Ubuntu are you using? Details are needed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this might be because of another update (e.g. `sudo apt upgrade`) has been run to upgrade your Linux kernel to `5.15.0-50-generic` to `5.15.0-52-generic` **before** attempting to install PHP. If the message prevents you to install PHP, you should consider rebooting first as some PHP extension may depend on Linux kernel-specific features.